# Golang build error: cannot assign *sqlx.DB to *sql.DB

Tags: go, sqlx

When I try to build my project, it says:

```
./main.go:140: cannot assign *sqlx.DB to db.Conn (type *sql.DB) in multiple assignment
```

My imports in main.go:

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "./network"
    "log"
    "./config"
    "./db"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)
```

My db.go is:

```
package db
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

var Conn *sql.DB
var Err error
```

And 140th line from main.go:

```
db.Conn, db.Err = sqlx.Open(config.Db.Type, config.Db.User+":"+config.Db.Pass+"@/"+config.Db.Name)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, `sql.DB` and `sqlx.DB` are different types. On another note, don't use relative path imports. They don't work in most cases, and were only kept for quick tests outside of GOPATH. Always use the full import path.

Comment: Thank you. It was too easy :D 
but why I shouldn't use relative path's? Now that's works fine.

Comment: The relative paths probably work fine because your only using `go build` or `go install` from within the package directory. This breaks when the go tool needs to reference your package by name. It also breaks you need to share types between packages because types are canonicalized by their import path, so type `T` from `./config` is a different type than type `T` from `../config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlx.Open` return a `sqlx.DB` struct ([here](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/d9bd385d68c068f1fabb5057e3dedcbcbb039d0f/sqlx.go#L238) the definition) that is different from the DB struct definition inside the `package databqase/sql`.
Change the `Conn` type to `sqlx.DB` and it should work.